# Shiny reactive plot multiple conditions in same dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm having trouble with the server.R getting shiny to plot the data based on drop down selections from the ui.R. I would like to select a 'Site' and a 'Parameter' and plot the 'Obs' that reflects that 'Site' and 'Parameter'. Obs as the Y and Date on the X. Here is some sample code.

```
Site_Names=data.frame(c(A=rep("A",10),B=rep("B",10),C=rep("C",10)))
Site_Names=Site_Names[,1]
Parameters=data.frame(c(pH=rep("pH",10),DO=rep("DO",10),Temp=rep("Temp",10)))
Parameters=Parameters[,1]
Obs=rnorm(30)
Dates=c(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "year", length.out =10 ),
seq(as.Date("2005/1/1"), by = "year", length.out =10 ),
seq(as.Date("1990/1/1"), by = "year", length.out =10 ))

data=data.frame(Site_Names,Parameters,Obs,Dates)

#ui.R

Sites=levels(data$Site_Name)
setNames(as.list(Sites), Sites)
params=levels(data$Parameters)
setNames(as.list(params), params)

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

 # Application title
  titlePanel("Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("site", "Select Site:", Sites),
      selectInput("parameters", "parameter", params)

    ),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("Plot")
  )
 )
  ))

#server.R

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    data[ , (input$Sites),]
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

      p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes(x=Dates, y=input$params and input$Sites))
      + geom_point(data$Obs)
      print(p)

      })
```

Comment: Could you provide an idea of what you'd want the plot to look like?

Comment: just a basic scatter or line plot with dates on the x axis and the 'Obs' data on the y axis. Ideally the Dates would also change based on the Site and Parameter selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subset` within your reactive expression to get the plot data.  Be careful though, as you can end up with null values if the parameter isn't included in the site data.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    subset(data, Site_Names == input$Sites & Parameters == input$params)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

      p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes(x = Dates, y = Obs)) + 
           geom_line()

      print(p)

      })
```

Comment: This is really close but something is still off. None of the Obs data show up on the plot...its completely blank regardless of which Sites or Params are selected. I appreciate you helping me out.

Comment: Thanks so much Jake.This was super helpful.  I got your code working.